# At what point do I update react state versus making a new call for fresh data?

Tags: reactjs

This is a generic question, I understand that, but I've been scouring the internet looking for a rule of thumb as to when I can update my state versus actually making a new api call to get fresh data.

Example, I receive a list of items, I add an item through the ui, which makes an api call to save that item in the db. I can just concat that to state.items, but now if I go back to the list of items, should I make a new api call for the list, or just use my state.items?

My concern is, at what point do I make a new call to get items from the db? How about if two people are editing the same item list, if I don't make a new call, then one is out of sync. What is general practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to reactjs. But I'll try to answer your question with my understanding of the reactjs concepts and your use-case.

1. When you make the API call to save to DB you can just concatenate the new item to state.items. If you're looping through your items and rendering it, then concatenating the new item shouldn't cause any trouble as reactjs will just render the changed content as long you provide the key as some unique value for each item.
2. If you want to maintain consistency across multiple users, then I'd advise you to use the real-time database like firebase which has triggers that get triggered when some changes are done to items in DB. Using these triggers you can update states of individual users.

references:

[firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)
[react firebase](https://medium.com/quick-code/how-to-integrate-react-redux-and-firebase-in-3-simple-steps-c44804a6af38)

Let me know if you need any more info.